# Custom RazorPages RazorViewEngine for .vbhtml file extensions

Tags: vb.net, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

There is a Github [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2738) that shares my frustration with the lack of support for Visual Basic in ASP.Net Core Web Applications and RazorPages.

The following quotes from other GitHub issues add to this frustration:

> [The .vbhtml razor engine from MVC 5 wasn't ported to Core primarily
>   because less than 1% of all VB web projects used it after 5 versions.](https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/issues/238#issuecomment-354927626)

and:

> [Unfortunately we have no any plans to support any other file
>   extensions but cshtml. That said, we won't be able to provide a
>   mechanism to configure/change the extension.](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/2125#issuecomment-370511887)

I managed to get .NET Core projects that support custom ViewEngines for [.pug](https://github.com/AspNetMonsters/pugzor) & [.md](https://github.com/hishamco/MarkdownViewEngine) file types to work for .vbhtml files, but could not get them working as RazorViewEngies which includes RazorPages.

So my questions are:

1. What do the other 99% use for VB Web Projects other than razor?
2. How can I create a .vbproj ASP.Net Core project that supports a RazorViewEngine that uses .vbhtml files with RazorPages?

Comment: In future, please provide a title that actually describes the issue. All the information in your title is duplicated in the tags and that is where that information should be. Your title is as much use as no title at all.

Comment: Ok title has been edited.

Comment: I also would preferably develop with vb.net instead of c# (I work with Xamarin and also have to use c#, as vb.net is not supported). I don't understand, that MS don't fully support vb.net. There are some hacks to use vb.net with asp.net core, but I would stay away as this can end in a dead end! So.. as soon as MS support vb.net officially (e.g. a project template for VB to asp.net core is available), I would change to vb.net. I the meantime, I HAVE to develop with c# and would  recommend you the same...